# Why Arr::get method clear slash and can it be fixed?

Tags: laravel

In the Laravel 6 / blade app for select input, I set array with Model class for key values, like: `\Users\Models`

I need to set default value for select input and with `jQuery` I keep default value in js variable:

```
var defaultNextAudienceLevel = '{{ Arr::get('tasks.defaultNextAudienceLevel') }}';
```

but alerting `defaultNextAudienceLevel` I see that slash symbol was cleared and my code does not work.

Reading here https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/helpers#method-array-get I did not find if `Arr::get()` makes clearing of data and how that can be fixed ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap `Arr::get('tasks.defaultNextAudienceLevel')` with `addslashes` function like this;

```
var defaultNextAudienceLevel = '{{ addslashes(Arr::get('tasks.defaultNextAudienceLevel')) }}';
```

This is because of the string literal definition of JavaScript, not from PHP nor Laravel.

For more details about the `addslashes` function, read this link; https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php